# No such entity with cartid = someid

Tags: error, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3, no-such-entity-exception, magento2.3.4

I am having this error in logs every time a customer placing new order from Magento 2.3.2 and now on Magento 2.3.4

```
report.CRITICAL: No such entity with cartId = "someid"{"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with cartId = "someid" at /mydir/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} []
```

After some digging it seems that when a customer places new order after success page its cart has the same products which has already ordered.
Magento instead of cleaning the cart throws the error.

I have tested this from magento GitHub but it seems don't work:
[Fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5807)

Any help please?

Comment: if there exist with customer id delete that customer seems attributes are not upgraded from that customer

Comment: Hi. I don't have only one id there. I have 2 ids from 2 different customers

Comment: Was had same issue with one site but id in error showing

Comment: And i have deleted that customer and error removed

Comment: I will try that then

Comment: No luck....Now I have another customer id with exception